# URL ShortCut Redirects

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, shortcut

This is my .htaccess command for making URL shortcuts:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .(.+)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.) ?open=encyclopedia&letter=$1&term=%1 [R,NC,L]
```

With the above works just fine:

```
example.com/Njumba ➛ example.com/?open=encyclopedia&letter=nj&term=njumba
```

Now, the problem is that it redirects merely one letter, but not two.
This is how I want it to be:

```
example.com/NJ ➛ example.com/?open=encyclopedia&letter=nj
```

Is this also achievable with .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.{1,2}).*$ /?open=encyclopedia&letter=$1&term=$0 [R,NE,QSA,L]
```

Comment: This command redirects me to: /?open=encyclopedia&letter=NJ&term=NJ, not to /?open=encyclopedia&letter=NJ&term=Njumba, thus opens only /?open=encyclopedia, not /?open=encyclopedia&letter=NJ

Comment: Unfortunately, what I receive with your command is: ?open=encyclopedia&letter=%c4&term=%c4%90 when I entered example.com/Đ .htaccess sees Đ as %C4%90, thus it takes only %C4... I need a workaround to that. I have Đ, Ž, LJ, NJ, Č, DŽ, Š. All the letters which can not be read/handled normally with the command.

Comment: And my updated comment is: 1) it works with NJ, LJ, Ž, Ć, Č, Š, Đ, but it does not with DŽ; 2) I updated your code to - RewriteRule ^(.{1,2}).*$ ?open=encyclopedia&letter=$1 [R,NE,QSA,L] because - with your solution - it opened /?open=encyclopedia&letter=NJ&term=NJ.

Comment: It's Serbian. Only `DŽ` now fails to work, all the others are loading fine. Then you would need to merge my command from the question above and this of yours and we are done. They will not work together if placed one below another.

Comment: Your question only mentioned English letters and solution already works for English letters. It is not fair to change the nature of the question by commenting.

Comment: Shall you help with this to the finish or not?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44491639/htaccess-unicode-recignisition-decode

Comment: **Of course I will**, once it works with all characters. It does not work with the letter **DŽ**; when I enter `example.com/DŽ`, it redirects me to `example.com/D`, not `/DŽ`. Currently, your answer is partially-working solution. The `example.com/DŽ` redirects me to `example.com/?open=encyclopedia&letter=D%C5`, thus not opening the right page.

Comment: See for Unicode characters you already have a separate question and I am digging my Apache source to answer that. This question however addresses only English language URLs hence it should be considered answered (for any single character language).

Comment: Okay then. Thank you for this part of answering. :-)