# .HTACCESS Unicode Recignisition/Encoding

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, unicode, shorthand

I am having a problem with my URL Shorthands in my .htaccess.

Namely, everything works fine with this (now old) code...

```
# URL ShortCut Maker.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.) ?open=encyclopedia&letter=$1&term=%1 [B,L,NC]
```

It shows URL correctly as `example.com/Modesty` (it shows the page as if the URL would be `/?open=encyclopedia&letter=m&term=modesty`), ***but*** the problem occurs when I enter:
`example.com/Šanti`, or
`example.com/Đin`, or 
`example.com/Žal`, 
`example.com/Čakra`, or
`example.com/Ćof`...
...if I enter any of these URLs - it shows the page as if I would enter:
`?open=encyclopedia` and not as
`?open=encyclopedia&letter=Š&term=Šanti`

EDIT: **Non-English letters in question/problem.**

Any solution to this?

Comment: What is expected rewrite for `example.com/Šanti` ?

Comment: Why don't you just use %1 and and extract first letter using mb_substr?

Comment: I added more clarification of my issue... ...I do not know how else to explain. @anubhava: `example.com/Šanti` should redirect to and open `?open=encyclopedia&letter=Š&term=Šanti`. This applies to all the other **Đ**, **Č**, **Ć**, **Ž** and **DŽ** letters. It is double-encoded and shortened. @Peter: what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your existing rule with rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

# executes repeatedly as long as there are more than 1 spaces in URI
RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s+(\S* .*)$" $1+$2 [N,NE]

# executes when there is exactly 1 space in URI
RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s(\S*)$" $1+$2 [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Z](?:[^\x00-\x7F]+|[A-Z])?).*$ ?open=encyclopedia&letter=$1&term=$0 [B,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^\x00-\x7F]+).*$ ?open=encyclopedia&letter=$1&term=$0 [B,L,QSA]
```

Negated character class `[^\x00-\x7F]` matches any character outside ASCII range.

Comment: So case 1 i.e. `example.com/Šazdini` is correct right?

Comment: ok try my updated rules now. Make sure these rules are at top of your .htaccess

Comment: Sorry now I can't understand anything. Request you to edit the question and clarify each of these cases.