# .HTACCESS Redirection Issues

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Namely, I have this .htaccess command...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\x00-\x7F]+).*$ ?open=encyclopedia&letter=$1&term=$0 [R,B,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Z](?:[^\x00-\x7F]+|[A-Z])?).*$ ?open=encyclopedia&letter=$1&term=$0 [R,B,L,QSA]
```

...And I have two issues with it now:
**Issue 1** - It loads shorthand of **all** of the letters **except** *A*, *S* and *O*. It displays blank white page instead of the actual page.
**Issue 2** - When I enter `http://example.com/Šandi (Astronomy)`, instead of redirecting me normally to `http://example.com/?open=encyclopedia&letter=Š&term=Šandi+(Astronomy)`, the URL is `http://example.com/?open=encyclopedia&letter=%25c5%25a0&term=%25c5%25a0andi+%2528Astronomy%2529`
**In other words:**
• When I remove the `[R]` flag from either of the Rules, the shorthand URL (id est - `example.com/A-O-S`) is as described in **Issue 1**.
• When I add the `[R]` flag, it redirects inappropriately, as described in **Issue 2**, and it *does not* display the page.

***Note:*** These problems include English and non-English letters (**Š**/**Đ**/**Č**/**Ć**/**Ž**).

As @anubhava suggested:
`<?php print_r($_GET); ?>` with `[R]` flag:
English: Array ( [open] => encyclopedia [letter] => V [term] => Vodolija (Astrologija) )
URL: ?open=encyclopedia&letterV&term=Vodolija (Astrologija)
Non-English: Array ( [open] => encyclopedia [letter] => ? [term] => Škorpija (Astrologija) )
URL: ?open=encyclopedia&letter=%c5&term=%c5%a0korpija%20(Astrologija)
`<?php print_r($_GET); ?>` without `[R]` flag:
English: Array ( [open] => encyclopedia [letter] => V [term] => Vodolija (Astrologija) )
URL: /Vodolija (Astrologija)
Non-English: Array ( [open] => encyclopedia [letter] => Š [term] => Škorpija (Astrologija) )
URL: /Škorpija (Astrologija)
As for the Index pages:
A - Array ( [open] => encyclopedia [letter] => A [term] => A ): It doesn't display the page, it shows blank white page.
O - Array ( [open] => encyclopedia [letter] => O [term] => O ): It doesn't display the page, it shows blank white page.
S - Array ( [open] => encyclopedia [letter] => S [term] => S ): It doesn't display the page, it shows blank white page.
As for the all the other Index pages, URL is Array ( [open] => encyclopedia [letter] => AnyLetter [term] => SameAnyLetter): It displays the page correctly... ...I do not see logic in it.

This is the new code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
#1 RewriteRule ([A-Z](?:[^\x00-\xFF].|\w).*) ?open=encyclopedia&letter=$2 [R,B,NE,L,QSA] # it loads DZH, but not the rest
#2 RewriteRule (([\x00-\xFF].|\w).*) ?open=encyclopedia&letter=$2 [R,B,NE,L,QSA] # it loads A-O-S and it loads DJ-ZH-LJ-NJ-SH
RewriteRule ^([A-Z](?:[^\x00-\x7F]+|[A-Z])?).*$ ?open=encyclopedia&letter=$1&term=$0 [B,NE,L,QSA]
```

When I delete the line #1,  the line #2 is working fine. When I delete the line #2, the line #1 is working okay. But they won't work together.
The line #2 displays all the letters except for the DŽ, and redirects properly.
The line #1 displays only the letter DŽ properly, won't redirect and won't load the rest.
With the line #2 enabled, the URL with `/DŽ` redirects to `/?open=encyclopedia&letter=D%c5`

UPDATE #6:

With the following code...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ((LJ).*) ?open=encyclopedia&letter=$2&term=$1 [R,NE,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ((NJ).*) ?open=encyclopedia&letter=$2&term=$1 [R,NE,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ((D\xC5\xBD).*) ?open=encyclopedia&letter=$2&term=$1 [R,NE,L,QSA]
RewriteRule (([\x00-\xFF].|\w).*) ?open=encyclopedia&letter=$2&term=$1 [R,NE,L,QSA]
```

...This happens:
• INDEX Pages: As for the „double-letter“ letters, it opens every letter correctly. As of the single letters, it loads every letter except **A**, **O** and **S**.
• TERM Pages: Considering it won't open **A**, **O** and **S**, therefore it won't open their Terms pages.
• `/Lav (Astrologija)` doesn't redirect to `/?open=encyclopedia&letter=L&term=Lav (Astrologija)`, but instead redirects to `/?open=encyclopedia&letter=L&term=Lav+%2528Astrologija%2529` thus won't open the proper page.
• It opens `/Š` properly and it redirects `/Škorpija (Astrologija)` properly to `/?open=encyclopedia&letter=Š&term=Škorpija (Astrologija)`
• It opens `/Đ` properly and it redirects `/Đavo` properly to `/?open=encyclopedia&letter=Đ&term=Đavo`
• Although it opens `/U` properly, `/Unuk Al Haj` redirects to `/?open=encyclopedia&letter=Un&term=Unuk%20Al%20Haj`, not opening the right page.
• Although it opens `/U` properly, `/Ugaoni Razmak` redirects to `/?open=encyclopedia&letter=Ug&term=Unuk%20Al%20Haj`, not opening the right page.
• Although it opens `/R` properly, `/Ribe (Astrologija)` redirects to `/?open=encyclopedia&letter=Ri&term=Ribe (Astrologija)`, not opening the right page.
• Although it opens `/V` properly, `/Vaga (Astrologija)` redirects to `/?open=encyclopedia&letter=Va&term=Vaga (Astrologija)`, not opening the right page.
• Although it opens `/U` properly, `/Umerenost` redirects to `/?open=encyclopedia&letter=Um&term=Umerenost`, not opening the right page.
• Although it opens `/K` properly, `/Kuće (Astrologija)` redirects to `/?open=encyclopedia&letter=Ku&term=Kuće (Astrologija)`, not opening the right page.

Comment: you use ASCII range though seem to get multibyte UTF-8, so in catched submasks those symbols may be broken.

Comment: Why do you have `R` flag in your rules now? Having `R` will do full redirect and will expose your internal URLs to clients. Also clarify in what ways [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44504653/548225) is not working for you?

Comment: @anubhava Yes, I want it to work correctly with `R`edirect as well as with shortcuts, that's what I added it. Sadly, when I used your code for the first time I did not fully test it. It shows errors as I explained in details above. And I updated my Question.

Comment: But using `R` will expose your internal URL to clients, that's not good for your SEO as well. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Question is un utter mess, you are showing the code but not explaining what are you actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Sorin I actually made it quite obvious what I am trying to accomplish, but, considering it includes non-English characters, it can be hard for some to understand correctly. I already chose the right answer and gave my bounty.

Comment: @De1an, no you didn't, you provided some examples, and no coherent explanation. There is no definition or explanation of what TERM or INDEX pages are for example. And the fact that you chose the answer doesn't mean anything, this question is useless for the site and it's users. The purpose of this site is not to solve your problems, it's to collaboratively build a knowledge base that anyone can use.

Comment: As far as I know, this site's purpose is to help web masters with their programming issues. And I used it to do just that. I already explained that I need shorthand-URLs for my INDEX and TERM pages, the fact that very few of you chose to try to help me resolve my issue speaks for itself. I explained what I need, I did not ask anyone to solve my problems, I asked for help... The fact that I have (had) some specific issues is not the actual problem, the actual problem is that very few individuals here chose to respond and seem to know how to work with the non-English alphabets...

Comment: I know, you are entitled to receive an answer because everyone else has to drop everything just to because you have a problem, and you can't be even bothered to explain what the problem is. Poor little you! I would have helped, but, I spent half an hour trying to figure out what exactly are you trying to achieve, an then saw this _Are you available? – De1an Jun 28 at 13:24_ and _Okay then. I suppose I will delete the Question. Thank you. – De1an Jun 28 at 18:30_ and _Likewise, not working. – De1an Jun 25 at 19:27_. You are rude and obnoxious. No body owes you anything!

Comment: So nobody on this site is obliged to answer anyone's questions. If that is the case, then nobody would bother using this site and posting their Questions. You truly have some issues. But not with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NE (no escape) flag:

```
# here are all 2 letters which we count as 1

RewriteRule ((D\xC5\xBD).*) ?open=encyclopedia&letter=$2&term=$1 [R,NE,L,QSA] # C5 BD is utf8 encoding of Ž
RewriteRule ((LJ).*) ?open=encyclopedia&letter=$2&term=$1 [R,NE,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ((NJ).*) ?open=encyclopedia&letter=$2&term=$1 [R,NE,L,QSA]

# one letter
RewriteRule (([\x80-\xFF].|\w).*) ?open=encyclopedia&letter=$2&term=$1 [R,NE,L,QSA]
```

Comment: No, unfortunately, it does not work. Nothing happens when I add the `NE`, it won't redirect.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: After lots of tweaking and testing, I found your code to be working. Thus, everything works just fine, except for the letter DŽ (it keeps opening the letter D, not the index page for the DŽ). I update my Question with the tweaked code. Take a look if you want.

Comment: DŽ are two letters ... You can create a rule for those two letters.

Comment: We have 3 sets of 2 letters which we count as 1, such as DŽ, LJ, NJ. How to create the rule?

Comment: After testing Your Rules, I updated my Main Question. See **Updated #6**.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you should be able to use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.)[^/]*$ ?open=encyclopedia&letter=$1&term=$0 [L,QSA]
```